# Calculating the sum of annual amounts when frequencies of payments differ

Tags: sql

I'm currently trying to write a select statement which calculates the Annual sum in one single column.

The problem I am facing is that there are several different payment frequencies e.g. I would have to multiply a monthly amount by 12 to get the annual, quarterly by 4, semi annual by 2 etc.

I have written a statement below which does this, however it demands that I group by the frequency and amount fields, which gives the undesired result.

```
select (case when Frequency='month' then SUM(cast(Amount as decimal(10,2))*12) 
else (case when Frequency='quarter' then SUM(cast(Amount as decimal(10,2))*4) 
else (case when Frequency='year' then SUM(cast(Amount as decimal(10,2))*1) 
else (case when Frequency='six months' then SUM(cast(Amount as decimal(10,2))*2) end) 
end)
end) end) as 'Total Annual Amount' 
from Table group by Frequency
```

I understand I maybe barking up the wrong tree as far as solving this problem, but the above is the closest I have gotten.

Hopefully I have been descriptive enough, if you need me to elaborate further please let me know

Comment: can you show some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your sum outside of your case:

```
select
sum (case when Frequency='Month' then (cast(amount as decimal(10,2))*12
     when Frequency='quarter' then...
end) as [Total Annual Amount]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I didn't try this variation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use WITH AS (assuming ORACLE)...

```
WITH dmap AS
 ( select 'Month' as duration, 12 as mult from dual
   UNION
   select 'Year' as duration, 1 as mult from dual
   UNION
   select 'Quater' as duration, 4 as mult from dual
   UNION
   select 'six months' as duration, 2 as mult from dual
 ) 
select sum(cast(Amount as decimal(10,2)) * mult)
from tab, dmap
where duration = frequency;
```